# Nginx as reverse proxy , rewrite or proxy pass request to docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I'm trying to use nginx as reverse proxy in front of a few applications which are on the same machine(Docker containers).
As a test, I tried to connect PHPmyAdmin to a URI like: [www.example.com/phpma](http://www.example.com/phpma)

This is how my location block looks like:

```
    location /phpma/ {
    proxy_pass         http://192.168.2.23:8081/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;  
    }
```

Everything works fine until you try to login or out.

Lets say when you put your username & pass and click login button, application redirects you to the home page. The URL is like :

https://example.com/index.php?route=/&route=%2F

Now, user faces an error, because the actual url from user side should have the /phpma uri added to the redirect link.
Lets say the above url should be like:

https://example.com/phpma/index.php?route=/&route=%2F

How can we overcome a situation like this, or in a production environment how we should design our application to address this?
Thanks

Comment: A very common solution is for your application to have a "base url" configuration setting that it uses to generate URLs.

Comment: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_PmaAbsoluteUri

Comment: Thank you guys. Both answers were useful and enlightening. I appreciate it.